# Highcharts range selector doesn'n work

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart. I want to display the range selector like this http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/range-selector
My code:

```
$('#timeline').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true,
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                var $moment = moment(this.value);

                return $moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "<br/>("+ $moment.format("HH:mm:ss") + ")";
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            grouping: false
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + ' - ' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                moment(this.point.low).format("DD MMMM HH:mm:ss") + " - " +
                moment(this.point.high).format("DD MMMM HH:mm:ss");
        }
    },

    series: JSON.parse('[{"name":"200","data":[{"x":0,"low":1438974756000,"high":1438974945000},{"x":0,"low":1438975321000,"high":1438975573000},{"x":0,"low":1438975697000,"high":1438980175000},{"x":0,"low":1439016907000,"high":1439017219000}]},{"name":"404","data":[{"x":0,"low":1438975005000,"high":1438975133000}]},{"name":"503","data":[{"x":0,"low":1438975197000,"high":1438975258000}]},{"name":"500","data":[{"x":0,"low":1438975637000,"high":1438975637000},{"x":0,"low":1439016542000,"high":1439016846000}]}]');
});
```

But range selector doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It does not look like you are using Highstock. As the documentation says, that is "Highstock only".

Comment: I'm use the highstock, I add the scrips: <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script> and <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

Comment: Then maybe it's just a case of the wrong constructor. Try `$('#timeline').highcharts('StockChart', {`.

Answer (score 0):

put:

```
allButtonsEnabled: true
```

in the range selector and try this. And set minimum date in xAxis:

```
min:Date.UTC(2015,0,1)
```